# Jquery toggleClass toggle's class but doesn't run animation more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is that I have a certain link that I want to pull the div upward over the screen if clicked but to be able to be clicked and pulled back down. Problem is, it only does it once and then no more. I check in Chrome's style checker and the class toggles on and off as expected, but it refuses to run the animation I'm lost

Here's a short code example:

```
$('#gallL a').unbind('click');
    $('#gallL').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('hlinks hlinksClicked');
        if($this.hasClass('hlinksClicked')) {
            $(foot).animate({
            'bottom':   $(window).height()-60}, 900, 'easeOutBounce');
        } else {
            $(foot).css({'top': '0px'});
            $(foot).animate({
            'top':      $(window).height()-60}, 900, 'easeOutBounce');
        }
    });
```

seems simple enough but no go :-(

Comment: What is the `foot` variable there? I suggest creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show an example of what's wrong.

Comment: what are the css styles for the element with the ID of gallL? and for the classes you toggle?

Comment: You're animating one time using the bottom value and other time using the top value

Comment: Idk I can't get it to output on jsfiddle. Basically I've rewritten this like 100 times. foot has a fixed position of {bottom: 0px, left: 0px} moves up, class toggled to hlinksClicked and then when clicked animates back to original position. It only runs completely through one cycle though

Comment: a demo is on [link](http://templates.smlivepro.com/laquanda). The username: stackoverflow and the pass: brainiak

Comment: Yeah that was it. I coded enough to know better but hey that's what other fellow coders are for. Thanks for the advice immediate fix. Thanks @amosmos :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're animating one time using the bottom value and other time using the top value.